# github action take vaule from json file into GITHUB_OUTPUT

Tags: bash, github, github-actions, cicd

I want to take content of JSON file into variable and use this variable to declare a GITHUB_OUTPUT

I tried this but it didn't work

```
            export min_req=$(cat min-requirements.json)
            echo $min_req
            echo "min_req= $min_req" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
```

and also added

```
      min-req-output: ${{ steps.get_min_requirement.outputs.min_req }}
```

it gave me an error

```
Error: Unable to process file command 'output' successfully.
Error: Invalid format
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem that we use it as an env in the next step

```
  - name: Prep debug
    id: prep
    run: |
      export min_req_file=$('cat min-requirements.json')
      echo "this the file ${min_req_file}"
      echo "min_req= ${min_req_file}" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
  - name: Debug
    env:
      JSON: ${{ steps.prep.outputs.json_output }}
    run: |
      echo "$JSON"
```

if we want to use it in another job

```
jobs:
  job1:
    outputs:
      min-req-output: ${{ steps.get_min_requirement.outputs.min_req}}
    steps:
      - name: Prep debug
        id: prep
        run: |
         export min_req_file=$('cat min-requirements.json')
         echo "this the file ${min_req_file}"
         echo "min_req= ${min_req_file}" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"job2:
        needs: job1
        env:
          min_req: ${{ needs.job1.outputs.min-req-output }}


  job2:
    needs: job1
    env:
      min_req: ${{ needs.job1.outputs.min-req-output }}
```